# Converting select list to uppercase

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to force the input of a select list to be uppercase as you type?

I've tried using the style attribute `text-transform:uppercase` , but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: (Just as a supplement) CSS is for *display* which is why you only see it take effect in the browser. To modify what actually gets recorded, see the already-posted responses.

Comment: What do you mean by a "select list"? A `<select>` element?  When you type into one of those, it jumps to an option that begins with the characters you entered and is completely case insensitive.  Did you mean a text input element like `<input type=text>` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: As an aside, all the people suggesting `onkeyup` to transform data need to [get with the times](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript) :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work for you -

Add this as the javascript event in your textbox/multiline textbox html control -

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Comment: Thank you. However it isn't working for me. The onkeyup event doesn't seem to get fired.

Comment: User can paste some test with a mouse, so there should be more processing - for example onblur, onchange to convert content to uppercase when focus lost.

Comment: Onblur does get fired, but this.value is undefined.

Comment: @Urbycoz - Assume you have already checked answer from @infoSetu which is in addition to my answer. Very useful indeed.

Comment: @Sachin- Yes. Turns out I wasn't using a standard select list. Thanks for your solution. I'm sure it's correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript event "OnKeyUp" , check the value there, and 
assign the value again after converting it to upper case.
This will ensure it stays in uppercase when you type .

Comment: The onkeyup event doesn't seem to get fired for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simply have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/gBXj6/

Thanking you.

Comment: @infoSetu - +1 for practically implementing my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sachin. :) +1 to you too for perfect suggestion.